# Publishing a Bot built using Bot-Framework also to Skype

Tags: skype, botframework

I am looking for information on publishing a Bot (written using Bot-Framework) to Skype. I can submit my bot for review within the Bot-Framework. Is it then also reviewed an published for Skype? Is there a need or way to link the Bot written using Bot-FW somehow to a Skype Bot? 
I am sorry if the answer is already out there somewhere in the FAQ's, but I have not found anything concerning that question at Bot-FW, on Skype Bots and here on stackoverflow. thank you for your help.

Comment: to clarify, we already have an up and running skype bot, so this is no question on how to add the skype channel to the bot-fw bot etc.
The question is purely concerning the review and approval process of a bot-fw bot and the connection of that process to the review and approval process of a skype bot.

Answer (score 0):

At this point these review processes are not connected see the Publish section in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs for details on how to publish a bot in Skype.